# UIButton: Center text in container and left image to the side

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift5

I want my `UIButton` to have the text centered, and then based on that, position an image to the left of it.

So far, I have this example (image below), but the text is not centered (check red line). Also, the blue background is intended to show the total width of this button.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show your code?

Comment: To be honest, I've just tried some extensions that only play with the title and image insets. Also, changing some settings in alignments and positioning inside the XIB file. No success so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually pretty simple. Just add the image's width to the button's `contentEdgeInsets.right`:

```
let t = "Text I want centered".uppercased()
let i = UIImage(named: "person.fill")

let button = UIButton(type: .system)
button.layer.borderWidth = 1
view.addSubview(button)

button.setTitle(t, for: .normal)
button.setImage(i, for: .normal)
button.contentEdgeInsets.right = i?.size.width ?? 0

button.sizeToFit()

print(button.frame.width) // prints "212.0"
print(button.titleLabel?.frame) // prints "(19.0, 1.0, 174.0, 18.0)"
```

The `print` statements show that the `titleLabel` is perfectly centered (since 19.0 + 174.0 + 19.0 = 212.0).

[image: result]